# using react lazy in CRA with cssmodules causes chunks to have duplicate css in production

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, code-splitting

I'm having similar issue seen here [Webpack chunk styles and react.lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632062/webpack-chunk-styles-and-react-lazy).

I'm using react lazy to with react-router to make route based code-splitting. I have reusable component called Block which uses cssmodules and two pages (actually more than two but thats for an example). Both of them are lazy loaded and use Block multiple times.

On production the styles from Block seem to be in both chunks for the Pages, so when I initially load PageA its respective chunk is loaded. Everything is fine. Going to PageB also causes its chunk to be loaded. Now when going back to PageA both chunks are loaded and styles from PageB overwrite everything thus breaking layout.

Removing lazy import fixes the problem but that not the solution. While it's my first react project I'm quite sure I did everything correctly at least to my understanding.

To illustrate the problem here is screenshot of styles tab from devtools after entering few pages and going back to initial one

[image]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you importing the CSS file in both components ?

Comment: No, the css is imported in Block and Block is imported in both pages

so Block.jsx has
import styles from './Block.module.scss';

and Page1/Page2 has:
import Block from 'Components/@Shared/Block';

I would have assumed that the code would go to some common chunk but that did not happen.

Comment: I am unsure about the problem. I tried to setup react and router quickly to address the problem. Couldn't find anything like that. You can have  a look at this codebase that i setup https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-jang-fesit?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Updated the codesandbox with a common component block. https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-ardinghelli-2ikcd

Comment: Just tried your sandbox locally with create-react-app, since I don't know if you can run it in production mode and have same issue https://ibb.co/kQrPShg https://ibb.co/kBKGDx1

Comment: Right. I am facing the same thing here.

Comment: I fixed it using `@loadable/component` instead of using React.lazy.

Comment: Hmm just tried it, replaced lazy with loadable but result is the same, still getting the css twice.

Comment: Import the `block` component using loadable also.

Comment: Yeah that works, even with lazy. Seems I have to also lazy load shared components. Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently I was too enthusiastic about it being the solution. When shared component accepts className from parent for more fine tuned styling and is lazy loaded its own styles will overwrite passed styles https://ibb.co/vxsGwvb. Probably because its styles will be loaded later due to it being lazy. This is mental :) I don't see any way around that :/

Answer (score 2):

tye this package works for me solved the same issue.

https://loadable-components.com/

```js
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
const OtherComponent = loadable(() => import('./OtherComponent'))
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  )
}
```

the nice part, it also split libs.

```js
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
const Moment = loadable.lib(() => import('moment'))
function FromNow({ date }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Moment fallback={date.toLocaleDateString()}>
        {({ default: moment }) => moment(date).fromNow()}
      </Moment>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem, and the solution for me was to import Layout component without using lazy, and use lazy for other page components
And this problem was not in webpack.config.js file